# Devices can't connect to network via switch

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch

I'm having an issue on my home network introducing a switch. The current, working setup includes a modem (no issues and plugged directly into WAN port on router), and a router (archer c7). The router is connected to several wifi devices (phones, laptops), via ethernet to a raspberry pi, and via ethernet to a desktop computer.

When I add a switch (tried both netgear GS208, tp link TL-SG105) to the ethernet connection between the desktop and router, suddenly, it's not able to connect to the network. I'm connecting the switch directly via ethernet to one of the router's ethernet ports, and the PC directly to the switch's ethernet port.

When I do this it gets a 169.254 IP address. When I set up an appropriate IP/subnet, I'm still not able to ping the pi or the router and there's no internet connection. When I connect the android device via usb-c, I don't get a connection either.

At first I thought it was an issue with the switch. I replaced the switch. It worked the first day, and stopped working the second day.

I think the cables are good, since when I remove the switch I'm using an ethernet male-male adapter to connect the cables from the desktop/router to each other directly.

Recently I changed the router to start rebooting every night since its performance was degrading over time without that. This issue started around the time that I did that, so I'm guessing it's somehow related but couldn't even begin to guess why or what to do to fix it (other than disabling automatic restarts and manually power cycling it when it starts to slow down).

Is there a way I can make the auto-rebooting router and the switch work happily with each other?

Comment: What make/model is your switch? Can you also please confirm that your modem is connected directly to your router's WAN/Internet port and that the switch sits between the PC and one of the router's LAN/Ethernet ports.

Comment: check that your nic is not forced into specific speed or mode. Go to Nic properties in Device Manager. Check the ADVANCED tab for LINK SPEED or the like.  different drivers call it something else.

Comment: Edit to add switch models, modem -> wan port, router <-> switch <-> pc config.

Comment: I have a "speed and duplex" setting that's set to "auto negotiation"

Comment: Do the link indicator LEDs light up on the port where you plug the router into the switch?

Comment: Yes, the desktop's stays lit and the router's comes on for a sec then goes back off.

Comment: That's a symptom of a physical cable issue. Try using a new cable between the switch and the router.

Comment: Can you make a diagram? How many spare devices, cables etc. do you have to do testing? What kind of switches are those? Unmanaged, Smart, Managed?